# How to highlight the Menu, when user clicks the Submenu by using php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to Highlight the Menus Dynamically by using Php & javascript. Below code working for only Menu's. But I want when I click Submenu for that menu it should be Highlighted.Please check the Code once

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cssmenu a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
        {
        //check if 1st level, then below condition
        //if(this.class() != "has-parent")
        //{
           // $(this).addClass("active");
        //} 
            //if not first level, assign active to parent of this
        //if(this.class()= "has-parent")
        //{
            $(this).addClass("active");
        //}     
            }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
 .active{
  background: #4FA9E4; color:#FFF;

}

<ul id="id">
<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="company.php">Company</a>

        <ul><li class="has-parent"><a href="a.php">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.php">b</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li  class="has-sub"><a href="patners.php">Patners</a>
        <ul><li><a href="c.php">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="d.php">d</a></li></ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.has-parent').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.has-sub').addClass('active');
});
```

If I understood right, that's what you are looking.

BTW, you have some syntax problems.

1. You didn't close the `<style>`.
2. The `<ul id="id">` is outside the `<body>`, isn't closed and apparently does nothing.
3. You are missing the `<head>`.

Final code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#cssmenu a').each(function(index) {
                    if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
                    {
                        //check if 1st level, then below condition
                        //if(this.class() != "has-parent")
                        //{
                        // $(this).addClass("active");
                        //} 
                        //if not first level, assign active to parent of this
                        //if(this.class()= "has-parent")
                        //{
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                        //}     
                    }
                });
                $('.has-parent').click(function() {
                    $(this).closest('.has-sub').addClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .active {
                background: #4FA9E4;
                color:#FFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cssmenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="has-sub">
                    <a href="company.php">Company</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-parent"><a href="a.php">a</a></li>
                        <li class="has-parent"><a href="b.php">b</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li  class="has-sub">
                    <a href="patners.php">Patners</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-parent"><a href="c.php">c</a></li>
                        <li class="has-parent"><a href="d.php">d</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where should i add these Lines..? After script added it doesnt working. Please tell me

Comment: @user3160105 I edited with the final code. I don't know exactly what you want to do with the commented lines.

Comment: ya now i did corrections still am not getting,please tell me where i should add the above lines in script.

Comment: I posted the final code with my lines included. They are just after the `$('#cssmenu a').each({...});` **edit** Sorry, the class `has-parent` was only present in the first submen. It should be in all of them. I'll correct the code.

Comment: yeah i checked your code. Submenu was highlighting. But i want when i click submenu,For that Main Menu Should highlight.

Comment: Wait... those links make a redirect, so you are highlighting the parent menu on click, but it goes away when the new page loads... you don't need that action to be executed on click. Don't you?

Comment: You need to highlight the corresponding menu on page load. That's probably what you were trying in the first place. What I need to help you, is that you post the real `href` of the `<a>`. Or they are `a.php`, `b.php`, etc?

Comment: from many days am trying this can you please give me the code for,when we click on sub menu main menu should highlight in php,javascript pls help me

Comment: Could you answer my previous question?